# How to add varnish to thumbor, s3 setup?

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, varnish, thumbor

client needs original s3 image or thumbnail image

A basic setup without varnish would look like:

```
client => s3 image
client => thumbor => s3 image (thumbor gets s3 image and creates thumbnail for the client)
```

I'd like to add varnish to cache images.  Where should I place varnish among servers?

```
1. client => s3 image becomse: client => varnish => s3 image
2. client => thumbor => s3 becomes any of the following I think

  1) client => varnish => thumbor => s3 image 
  2) client => thumbor => varnish => s3 image
  3) client => varnish => thumbor => varnish => s3 image
```

I guess 3) would be best if I could set it up.. but I guess would be hard to set up 
How about 1) vs 2) which one should I prefer?